# Easy Skeletal Javascript System

Tags: javascript, system, anchor

I'm looking for an easier way to repeat this process and make it so I don't have to go through each part individually. Maybe I should store the parts in an object, and tell which other part it connects to.

I guess my question would have to be:
`What would an easy way to make a skeletal system be?`

```
var drawPlayer = function() {
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#FFF';
    ctx.lineWidth = 3;
    ctx.beginPath();
    //body
    var temp = p2c(player.bodyLength/2, player.body);
    ctx.moveTo(player.pos.x + temp[0], player.pos.y - temp[1]);
    ctx.lineTo(player.pos.x - temp[0], player.pos.y + temp[1]);
    var humorusAnchor = [player.pos.x + temp[0], player.pos.y - temp[1]];
    var thighAnchor = [player.pos.x - temp[0], player.pos.y + temp[1]];
    //left humorus
    var temp = p2c(player.arms.humorusLength, player.arms.leftHumorus);
    ctx.moveTo(humorusAnchor[0], humorusAnchor[1]);
    ctx.lineTo(humorusAnchor[0] - temp[0], humorusAnchor[1] + temp[1]);
    var leftForearmAnchor = [humorusAnchor[0] - temp[0], humorusAnchor[1] + temp[1]];
    //right humorus
    var temp = p2c(player.arms.humorusLength, player.arms.rightHumorus);
    ctx.moveTo(humorusAnchor[0], humorusAnchor[1]);
    ctx.lineTo(humorusAnchor[0] - temp[0], humorusAnchor[1] + temp[1]);
    var rightForearmAnchor = [humorusAnchor[0] - temp[0], humorusAnchor[1] + temp[1]];
    //left forearm
    var temp = p2c(player.arms.forearmLength, player.arms.leftForearm);
    ctx.moveTo(leftForearmAnchor[0], leftForearmAnchor[1]);
    ctx.lineTo(leftForearmAnchor[0] - temp[0], leftForearmAnchor[1] + temp[1]);
    //right forearm
    var temp = p2c(player.arms.forearmLength, player.arms.rightForearm);
    ctx.moveTo(rightForearmAnchor[0], rightForearmAnchor[1]);
    ctx.lineTo(rightForearmAnchor[0] - temp[0], rightForearmAnchor[1] + temp[1]);
    //left thigh
    var temp = p2c(player.legs.thighLength, player.legs.leftThigh);
    ctx.moveTo(thighAnchor[0], thighAnchor[1]);
    ctx.lineTo(thighAnchor[0] - temp[0], thighAnchor[1] + temp[1]);
    var leftCalveAnchor = [thighAnchor[0] - temp[0], thighAnchor[1] + temp[1]];
    //right thigh
    var temp = p2c(player.legs.thighLength, player.legs.rightThigh);
    ctx.moveTo(thighAnchor[0], thighAnchor[1]);
    ctx.lineTo(thighAnchor[0] - temp[0], thighAnchor[1] + temp[1]);
    var rightCalveAnchor = [thighAnchor[0] - temp[0], thighAnchor[1] + temp[1]];
    //left calve
    var temp = p2c(player.legs.calveLength, player.legs.leftCalve);
    ctx.moveTo(leftCalveAnchor[0], leftCalveAnchor[1]);
    ctx.lineTo(leftCalveAnchor[0] - temp[0], leftCalveAnchor[1] + temp[1]);
    //right calve
    var temp = p2c(player.legs.calveLength, player.legs.rightCalve);
    ctx.moveTo(rightCalveAnchor[0], rightCalveAnchor[1]);
    ctx.lineTo(rightCalveAnchor[0] - temp[0], rightCalveAnchor[1] + temp[1]);
    ctx.stroke();
};
```

Comment: You need to use these lyrics: The toe bone connected to the heel bone,
The heel bone connected to the foot bone, 
The foot bone connected to the leg bone,
The leg bone connected to the knee bone,

Comment: lol, yes.. I have it working, but doing this process over and over for each bone is a far bit too much...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you will have an array of joints or bones like so

```
class Bone {
    Bone parent;
    Vector tail; // Translation from the parent node's tail
    public:
        Bone(Vector tail, Bone parent);
};
```

Then you have the body defined like so

```
Bone bones[] = /* Array sizing */
Bone root = Bone(Vector(0,0), null); // I think this is called the rhomboid, Not sure, area between the shoulders
Bone leftShoulder = Bone(Vector(-10,0), root);
Bone rightShoulder= Bone(Vector(10,0), root);
Bone leftElbow = Bone(Vector(-10, 0), leftShoulder);
Bone rightElbow = Bone(Vector(10,0), rightShoulder);
// and so on...
bones = [root, leftShoulder, rightShoulder, ...];
```

And then to draw it, you would do this:

```
foreach(bone in bones){
    Vector offset = bone.tail;
    Bone p = bone.parent;
    while(p.parent != null){ p = p.parent;offset+=bone.tail; }
    Vector parentOffset = offset - bone.tail;
    drawBone(offset, parentOffset);
}
```

Comment: I'm using javascript... This is like giving a kid some weird chinese book. I'll attempt to piece it all together .-.